# Simulate a "ENTER" keyPress for Excel Userform with powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, keypress, userform

I am trying to open my `.xlsm` file with a Userform that is in a workbook Event OPEN and create an ENTER keypress simulation so the `MACRO` starts. I know that I can call the macro directly but we are using the Userform to show some information while the code is running.

I have built a `Powershell` script but as soon as I open my excel file my code stops there and does not execute the rest needed until I close the excel file. Is it a way to force my code to jump to the next execution or a different solution. thank you advance

```
 $excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
  #open file
 $FilePath = 'Q:\Detail\DT_HAL_TMPC\App\POFI_Planificateur_Taches_Exec.xlsm'

 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

 #make it visible (just to check what is happening)
 $excel.Visible = $true

 $workSheet = $workBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

 $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

 sleep 10
 $wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

as soon as I close my excel file the `.sendKeys` works but I want to do it while my excel file is open, not close

Comment: Use [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~')

Comment: Did not work unfortunatly my code is block due to the userform initialization